# internal reliability scores below .70

Tags: reliability

When one is assessing the reliability of one instrument and the value is under .70 and you then eliminate the item/items that are mentioned that if eliminated would increase the reliability score, should you also remove them from the total scores of each participant? For example, if item number 30 is eliminated and some participants got a point from getting that answer correct, would that mean that I should no longer given them scores on that particular items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Removing an item from a test means disregarding all subjects' scores on that item, which means recomputing total scores with that item removed.